# how to use .antMatchers("/").not() method in spring security, and i am using spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-security, permissions, roles, urlauthenticationchallenges

I wanted to permit 100 url's if the user do not have the given permission and also want to restrict him only to a single page, how can i do it using spring security, or can someone help me with antMatchers() to proceed with my requirement, thank you in advance.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http 
    .authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/p1/**").permitAll() 
 .antMatchers("/p2","/p3","/p4").wantRestrictIfItHasRole.access("hasRole('ROLEA')") 
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: can you show your security configuration class.  can you explain in a bit detail with example

Comment: i have a role -> roleA and a user -> userA and pages p1, p2, p3, p4 
If the userA has roleA then userA should only have access to p1 and should be restricted in p2, p3, p4.

I want this to be done using antMatchers()

                `http
  .authorizeRequests()                                                                
   .antMatchers("/p1/**").permitAll()   
                        .antMatchers("/p2","/p3","/p4").wantRestrict.access("hasRole('ROLEA'))                           
   .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
   
  // ...`

Comment: so what is the problem here. Please put the relavent code in the question

Comment: I want to implement `!hasAnyRole("ROLEA")` in terms of antMatchers(). Is there a way we can do this using antMatchers()

Comment: `antMatchers` support regex. so you can try something like this `antMatchers([^(matching_pattern)])`. I have not tried it though. Give it a try. This should match all the patterns which are not matching_pattern. Notice the `^`

Comment: thank you @pvpkiran, I am able to get the pages using regex, but i wanted to know how to restrict the access if the user has a certain role.

Comment: `antMatchers([^(matching_pattern)]).hasRole("ROLEA")`

Comment: Let me know if it works